# 'ElseIf' must be preceded by a matching 'If' or 'Elsif'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Hi I am currently coding a blackjack game for a school project. But I have encountered an error. When I run my program the code says 'ElseIf' must be preceded by a matching 'If' or "ElsIf'. I have tried lots of different arrangements but I cannot figure it out. Below is my code for the Msgbox.

Please Help

```
    Dim responseYouWon = MsgBox(youWonMsg, style, youWonTitle)
    Dim responseYouLost = MsgBox(youLostMsg, style, youLostTitle)
    Dim responseYouDrew = MsgBox(youDrewMsg, style, youDrewTitle)

    If PlayerSum < 21 And PlayerSum > ComputerSum Then
        If responseYouWon = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            btnPlayAgain.PerformClick()
        Else
            btnQuit.PerformClick()
        End If
    End If

    ElseIf ComputerSum > 21 And PlayerSum < 21 Then
    If responseYouWon = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        btnPlayAgain.PerformClick()
    Else
        btnQuit.PerformClick()
    End If

    ElseIf ComputerSum > 21 And ComputerSum < 21 Then
    If responseYouWon = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        btnPlayAgain.PerformClick()
    Else
        btnQuit.PerformClick()
    End If

    ElseIf PlayerSum = 21 And ComputerSum > 21 Then
    If responseYouWon = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        btnPlayAgain.PerformClick()
    Else
        btnQuit.PerformClick()
    End If

    ElseIf PlayerSum = 21 And ComputerSum < 21 Then
    If responseYouWon = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        btnPlayAgain.PerformClick()
    Else
        btnQuit.PerformClick()
    End If

    ElseIf ComputerSum < 21 And ComputerSum > PlayerSum Then
    If responseYouLost = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        btnPlayAgain.PerformClick()
    Else
        btnQuit.PerformClick()
    End If

    ElseIf PlayerSum > 21 And ComputerSum < 21 Then
    If responseYouLost = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        btnPlayAgain.PerformClick()
    Else
        btnQuit.PerformClick()
    End If

    ElseIf ComputerSum = 21 And PlayerSum <> 21 Then
    If responseYouLost = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        btnPlayAgain.PerformClick()
    Else
        btnQuit.PerformClick()
    End If

    ElseIf ComputerSum = PlayerSum Then
    If responseYouDrew = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        btnPlayAgain.PerformClick()
    Else
        btnQuit.PerformClick()
        End If

    ElseIf PlayerSum > 21 And ComputerSum > 21 Then
    If responseYouDrew = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        btnPlayAgain.PerformClick()
    Else
        btnQuit.PerformClick()
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Delete the `End If` in line 11 and add it at the very end of your sub

Comment: This is not something you need to ask question here

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can make this **way** easier on yourself:

```
If PlayerSum > 21 Then PlayerSum = 0
If ComputerSum > 21 Then ComputerSum = 0

Dim response As MsgBoxResult
If PlayerSum > ComputerSum Then
    response = MsgBox(youWonMsg, style, youWonTitle)
ElseIf ComputerSum > PlayerSum Then
    response = MsgBox(youLostMsg, style, youLostTitle)
Else
    response = MsgBox(youDrewMsg, style, youDrewTitle)
End If

If response = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
    btnPlayAgain.PerformClick()
Else
    btnQuit.PerformClick()
End If
```

But to your original code... look at the extra `End If` closing statement on line 11.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the End If in line 11 
and but it at the end of the sub